# Where can I find a dog to fart on?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I'm trying to get the **Dog Whistle** Achievement, which requires that I assume gnome form and fart on a dog.

Problem is, I can't find a dog anywhere. The only one I've ever seen in the game is Stans dog that he summons as part of an attack, and I'm pretty much at the endgame. Where are the dogs? I would very much like to fart on one.

Comment: The last two sentences are amazing and must be used as often as possible in normal conversation.

Comment: Who let the dogs out?

Comment: To the hot network questions you go!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to the title, you should be looking for a wolf rather than a dog.  As you saw yourself, there aren't many dogs to be found, if any at all.

To **find a wolf**, go to the **lost forest**, take a few turns, and you should easily find yourself *a wolf to fart on*.

A common issue with this is that if you progressed to the **late game**, after the zombie outbreak (which you have), the **wolves** in the forest **will be replaced with the Nazi zombies**.  To fix this, you should finish the game storyline, which will bring back the  wolves.

It is recommended that you use **Cup A Spell** for this to keep yourself out of combat,  and make sure that after you fart on a wolf you maintain your gnome form until achievement completes, since it can be delayed.

**Wolves in Canada won't work** for the achievement.
*Guess the Canadian medical insurance covers getting farted upon.*